# How to pass an array between methods?

Tags: c#, arrays, parameter-passing, return-value

I'm following along in a book and trying the 'challenges'. Here I'm running into a problem with properly returning and passing an array between methods. Something goes wrong with returning the array, especially from the second method, and then passing it to third to print.

I understand the stack, heap, values and references on the conceptual level, but something clearly goes 
 wrong.
Each method appears to work otherwise.

```
using System;

namespace PracticeArray
{
    class Program
    {
        static int[] GenerateNumbers()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a number to generate array from:");
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            int inputNumber = Convert.ToInt32(input);

            int[] generatedArray = new int[inputNumber];
            for (int i = 0; i < generatedArray.Length; i++)
            {
                generatedArray[i] = i;
            }

            return generatedArray;
        }

        static int[] Reverse(int[] arrayToReverse)
        {
            int count = arrayToReverse.Length;

            int[] arrayToReturn = new int[count];

            count--;

            for (int i = 0; i < arrayToReturn.Length; i++)
            {
                arrayToReturn[i] = arrayToReverse[count--];

            }

           return arrayToReturn;
        }

        static void PrintNumbers(int[] numbersToPrint)
        {

            foreach (int singleNumber in numbersToPrint)
            {
                Console.Write(singleNumber + ", ");
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            int[] numbers = GenerateNumbers();
            Reverse(numbers);
            PrintNumbers(numbers);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `return` does not overwrite the input parameter. Try `int[] newNumbers = Reverse(numbers); PrintNumbers(newNumbers);`

Comment: Hi! you just need to assign back to the numbers variable! `numbers = Reverse(numbers);`

Comment: With `Reverse(numbers);`, you're doing the equivalent of dropping the new array on the floor. You need to receive it somehow (e.g. assign it to a variable, or pass it directly into `PrintNumbers`). This has little to do with arrays and more to do with the basics of returning values from methods.

Comment: Why not use `Array.Reverse` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## The problem

The array you return is a new array:

Take a look in your `Reverse` function.  You create a new array called `arrayToReturn` and return that array.  You also never modify the original input array `arrayToReverse`.

```
        static int[] Reverse(int[] arrayToReverse) // this input array is never modified
        {
            int count = arrayToReverse.Length;
            // ...
            arrayToReturn = new int[count]; // Here is the new array
            // ...
            return arrayToReturn; // you return the new array
        }
```

Now look at where you called `Reverse` you passed in some generated numbers, but you ignore the return value of the function so you never find out what the new array is.  Remember we already established above that you don't modify the elements of the input array.  So `numbers` will remain unchanged.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] numbers = GenerateNumbers();
            Reverse(numbers); // you ignored the return value of `Reverse`
            PrintNumbers(numbers); // These are the original unreversed numbers
        }
```

## To Fix

#### Option #1 - New variable to store the result

To fix this, store the array returned from `Reverse` in a variable and print those numbers.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] numbers = GenerateNumbers();
            int[] reversedNumbers = Reverse(numbers);
            PrintNumbers(reversedNumbers);
        }
```

#### Option #2 - Reuse the same variable to store the result

In this option you simply discard the original array by taking the new reversed numbers array returned from `Reverse` and assigning it to the `numbers` variable.  After that assignment, `numbers` will refer to the reversed array that was returned from `Reverse`.  The original array is orphaned and forgotten - eventually garbage collected.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] numbers = GenerateNumbers();
            // repurpose the `numbers` variable to store the result.
            numbers = Reverse(numbers);
            PrintNumbers(numbers);
        }
```